# I want so solve Image Capthca Using python

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, recaptcha, captcha

I want to automate a site, that asks for captcha to be solved, that is a image captcha, It asks to select all box with bus etc, found multiple options to solve simple captchas using python but nothing free realated to image captcha

I want a part of a code or any library in python that I can study and get my problem solved

Comment: Do it at random, that will be easier.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Can you please suggest any article for this? or something similar

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation

Answer (score -1):

Use 2captcha or make your own AI system for solving them.